# Webdriver.io, findElement by something

Tags: javascript, input, selenium-webdriver, импорт, coffeescript

Я пишу тесты на **CoffeeScript** с использованием **Webdriver.io** и **mocha**. Код обрабатывается с помощью компилятора **CoffeeScript**.

В рамках теста мне необходимо прикрепить файл к *input type="file"*. Как правило материалы из интернета предлагают сделать это следующим образом:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendkeys("filepath");
```

Однако при запуске теста возникает ошибка **By is not defined**.

Если попытаться подключить **import org.openqa.selenium.By**, то появляется другая ошибка:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By
          ^
Error: unexpected .
```

В чём может заключаться данная проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_path = browser.uploadFile(FILE_PATH) # путь к загружаемому файлу на устройстве
$('div.my_selector').setValue(file_path)
```